# Write multiple setInterval() at once with the same second parameter

Tags: javascript, setinterval, syntactic-sugar

I'm making a clock UI that shows analog, digital, and date at the same time. I made a function for each case that requires setInterval(). I wanted to know if I could write them at once in case there were many.

```js
function getAnalog(){
  return 'something';
}
function getDigital(){
  return 'something';
}
function getDate(){
  return 'something';
}

setInterval(getAnalog,1000);setInterval(getDigital,1000);setInterval(getDate,1000);
getAnalog();getDigital();getDate();
```

Comment: make one function that calls each function? `[getAnalog, getDigital, getDate].map(fnc => { fnc(); return setTimeout(fnc, 1000); });`

Comment: Make one function that calls  your other three, and use a single interval.

Comment: Not related to the question, but updating a clock using `setInterval` with timeout `1000` will cause the clock to drift or jump depending on implementation. I would use `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: `setInterval` callback functions don't need to `return` anything.  Their return value is ignored.  So that part of your example seems a little unnecessary (confusing as to what your intent was).

Comment: @Wyck I just didn't want to leave my functions empty :)

Comment: @epascarello Does setTimeout and setInterval work the same here? Excuse my ignorance, I'm a bit new to JS.

Comment: @BiplobBaruaRocky I picked the timer in my example and FYI, intervals and timerouts are not accurate as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another function that calls all of the other functions.

```js
function getAnalog(){
  return 'something';
}
function getDigital(){
  return 'something';
}
function getDate(){
  return 'something';
}
const fn = () => {
    getAnalog();
    getDigital();
    getDate();
};
setInterval(fn, 1000);
fn();
```

Comment: I would hope that this approach seems obvious in hindsight.  It's a very fundamental notion to be able to do more than one thing in response to a single event like this (with a function).  The same approach applies for any kind of callback, like a `click` handler for a button -- you only need the one callback function (`fn` in your example), but you can make that callback function do more than one thing (`getAnalog`, `getDigital`, `getDate`, etc. in your example).

Answer (score 0):

```
// create an array with each function
const functions = [
  function getAnalog(){
    return 'something';
  },
  function getDigital(){
    return 'something';
  },
  function getDate(){
    return 'something';
  },
]

functions.forEach(fn => {
  setInterval(fn, 1000) // create each interval in the loop
  fn() // run each function in the loop
})
```

One interval version:

```
// create an array with each function
const functions = [
  function getAnalog(){
    return 'something';
  },
  function getDigital(){
    return 'something';
  },
  function getDate(){
    return 'something';
  },
]

setInterval(() => functions.forEach(fn => fn()), 1000)
functions.forEach(fn => fn())
```

Comment: It's tidier, but this still creates multiple intervals when one would do the job.

Comment: @DBS yes it is, but OP didn't specify if this all should be one interval or not, but it makes sense to be just one

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thank you for the answer. What should I change, If I wanted only one interval?